# Access class hierarchy attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, class-hierarchy, class-attributes

Given a class named `DataStream`

```
class DataStream(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = start
        self.input_val = input_val
```

and a class named `InDataStream`:

```
class  InDataStream(DataStream):
    def __init__(self):
        super( InDataStream, self).__init__()
        self.ready = ready

stream = InDataStream()
```

I want to send `DataStream` part of `stream` into a function, something like:

```
function(stream.DataStream)
```

Is there any nice way to do this task?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, `stream` (or any `InDataStream`) doesn't *have a* `DataStream`, it **is a** `DataStream`.

Comment: Are you asking how to sort of downcast `InDataStream` to a `DataStream` and hide its `InDataStream` qualities?  Why do you want to do this?  This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I kind of want to use `indatastream` like a `datastream` by neglecting its `ready` attribute.

I want to send indatastream's datastream part into a function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to access an instance of `DataStream` from an instance of class `InDataStream`, then you may consider using composition instead of inheritance:

```
class InDataStream(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ready = ready
        self.datastream = DataStream()
```

Then you can do:

```
stream = InDataStream()
function(stream.datastream)
```

Comment: Thanks ... I completely overlooked that I was missing that ...
It's  solved :)

Comment: Is there anyway this can be achieved without changing the class structure ?